# Characters allowed in course name while passing it through the webserive in Desire2Learn

Tags: desire2learn

While creating a course I send the character to course name which when I looked up in Desire2Learn got transferred to a "?". The character send was dash (not the one that you can directly entered from keyboard (-) but little bit longer (like in "Course – name")  - I got that from while copying the name from word). However this leads to the question which character are supported in D2L course name so that we can send the simmilar character set. Also what will happen if the character is for a chinese or polish course name?

[updated - 15/12] - When I am sending Japanese character in place of username - it is also showing them as a series of "?"

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved - actually I was using Ascii encoding to convert the data into bytes before submitting to POST. Change to UTF8 encoding now resolved the issue.